# Does spam-marked email effect reputation if server is whitelisted?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, spam-prevention

I send email via SendGrid from outside a company to many employees from one company.

This company whitelisted the sender IP address, so that no email we send is automatically marked as spam. If some of the employees mark these emails as spam in their Outlook, does that effect the email reputation we have at SendGrid?

Or does the exchange not communicate the spam flags to the sender server if the sender IP is whitelisted?

Comment: Depends on what you mean when you say the employees marked as spam. If that data feeds back in to a global email filtering system like Office 365, or Barracuda, then it could change the overall reputation of your entire domain name or email service in general. Making it generally harder for you to send email to anyone else. If it feeds back in to sendgrid they may suspend your account.

Comment: okay, that is something i understand already. The question is if the sender server is whitelisted so validated as a trusted source does the exchange feeds back the information that some employees mark mails as spam to a global list or sendgrid?
I thought that must be something that secure the reputation if some marks "internal" or "trusted" mails as spam for fun.